# Accidentally moved a directory using Dolphins GUI. After cancelling, the dir is empty

Tags: files, dolphin

In Dolphins places menu on a Debian system I dragged a directory (*Desktop*) to another (*Home*) by accident. I then canceled the the action. I then killed the window.

The Desktop had a shortcut to another drive, now many of the sub directories inside that drive have been emptied. I've done a search for some of the files but nothing comes up.

Are all these files lost now? What happened here?

Comment: Have you looked for `Home/Desktop`?

Comment: @roaima Yes. That is the location of the item "Desktop" in places, which has the shortcut to the other drive. I don't think these files are recoverable. Just want to understand why they have been deleted.

Comment: I would _expect_ to find the missing files moved along with the to level directory. If they have vanished that's definitely a bug that needs reporting upstream

Comment: @roaima The files are gone. I dont even know if that's why they got deleted but that's the only thing I did that might have done it. Who should I report it to?

Comment: There's a command-line tool called `reportbug` that should help. There may be a graphical equivalent; I don't know. The package to report the bug against would be `dolphin`. You can also look to see if it's already been reported at https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?pkg=dolphin